# A matrix commuting with all matrices from $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is the zero matrix

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{R})=\{X\in\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R}): \mathrm{tr}(X)=0\}$ the Lie algebra of $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$, i want show that, if $X\in\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is such that:
$[X,Y]=0$, for all $Y\in\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{R})$, then: $X=0$.
Where, for all $A,B\in\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{R})$:
$$[A,B]=AB-BA.$$
I have no idea how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Take for $Y$ a lot of matrices and see what happens.

Comment: @RafaelMrđen i don't understand your answer.

Comment: For example, try $Y = E_{ij}$, for $i\ne j$, the matrix with a $1$ in the $i$th row and $j$th column, $0$'s everywhere else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centre of Lie Algebra $sl_n(\mathbb{F})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135917/centre-of-lie-algebra-sl-2-mathbbf)

Comment: Since $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is simple and the centre $Z$ is an ideal, it must be zero or $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{R})$. Since the Lie algebra is not abelian, it follows that $Z=0$.